# ArrayList.trimToSize() method

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

Can I use [ArrayList.trimToSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) method in dynamic arrayList ?

1. If I use it , what will be happened ?
2. Can I get any benefits on using this method on dynamic ArrayList.
3. In which case, I should use this method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's said in java api?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamic `ArrayList`*?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran **Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size.**

Comment: @RohitJain , I declare as **ArrayList<Interger> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();** but not as **ArrayList<Interger> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);** .

Comment: @Cataclysm FYI, both the declarations have same effect. `10` is the default capacity. The value you pass to constructor is not fixed size, it's initial capacity.

Comment: @Cataclysm Both lists are dynamic, except that the latter is initalised with a specific capacity, but that won't prevent it from growing if required.

Comment: That said, there is no such thing as dynamic ArrayList. You can say that `ArrayList` is a dynamically increasing array.

Comment: @assylias ,Oh ! nice, If so what is is this method used for.

Comment: @RohitJain , thanks for nice saying "ArrayList is a dynamically increasing array."

Comment: @Cataclysm If you know you are going to put 10 million entries in your list, you can size it to 10 million from the beginning to avoid unnecessary resizing. If you don't, the list will start with an `Object[10]` then, when full, will be resized to an `Object[15]` etc. until reaching 10 million. Those resizing operations can be time consuming so you would in that case use an `ArrayList<>(1000000);`. For small lists it does not make a big difference.

Comment: By "dynamic", I think you mean mutable (as opposed to, say, the singleton empty list returned by `Collections.emptyList()`). Calling `trimToSize()` does not return an immutable list, it's still a regular ArrayList, the only change is that the backing array is copied to an array with no empty space at the end for new elements. The array will be grown again if you add more elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs you link yourself:

> Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.

Internally an `ArrayList` stores an array that holds all the items. At certain moments the `ArrayList` will "expand" this array by copying all values into a larger array. This happens whenever an item is being added and the required capacity is bigger than the current one. What happens at this point is the following line of code:

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
```

In essence this will create a new array that is 1.5 times the size of the current one. What this method does is resize the internal array so that it has no empty space left.

1. Nothing will happen that's visible to you. You won't lose any data, it's just smaller backing array. Adding data to the arraylist will again expand the array normally.
2. I assume you mean a "normal" `ArrayList`. If you use this, you will reduce the memory used but it will also be futile if you will still add data after that AND it is pretty useless for small lists. If you have an `ArrayList` of many, many items and you're sure you don't want to add anymore then you can call this method to reduce some memory footprint.
3. See above. I don't think it's very likely you'll ever use this.

`trimToSize()` from the source:

```
public void trimToSize() {
    modCount++;
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    if (size < oldCapacity) {
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: This 'threshold' strategy was for HashMaps. The ArrayList increases the size of its Array only when the required size is greater than the actual size. BTW: It may be important to note that the size of the array is not increased by a constant *value*, but by a constant *factor*. In the first case, inserting `n` elements would have quadratic complexity, but in the second case, the complexity is linear.

Comment: @Marco13: You're right, I was about to edit it after looking at the source code.

Comment: I have poor experience on it ,so I can't discuss anythings with all of you . But I got many useful knowledges for me. Thanks..

Comment: It's more complicated than `newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)`, since this would not increase the size of an array of size 1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's simple:

1. The ArrayList will be trimmed to its current size
2. Yes, you can minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance
3. When you want to trim the ArrayList and minimize its storage

But seriously: There are few occasions where this method should be called (I personally have *never* used it). It's related to how an ArrayList is implemented: As the name suggests, the ArrayList internally uses an array to store the data. When you add new elements to the ArrayList, the size of the array is increased as needed. When you add 1000000 elements to the ArrayList, then the internal Array will have a .length of at least (!) 1000000. When you afterwards remove 999999 elements from the ArrayList, then the internal array will *still* have a .length of at least 1000000. The call to `trimToSize` will then make sure that the internal array only has the required size (1, in this case). But again: This is hardly ever necessary or beneficial. You should usually not work on `ArrayList` instances anyhow, but on the (more general) `List` interface.