# Use of ArrayList#trimToSize() method?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

From [a recently posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478182/arraylist-trimtosize-method) I came across [ArrayList#trimToSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29) which reduces the size of the backing array to current size of collection.

Quoting javadoc

> Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current
>   size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of
>   an ArrayList instance.

And the Javadoc says that the application can use to reduce the memory footprint of backing array. If I am not wrong this method won't be useful for small sizes as the cost of some references won't hurt that much.

But because of the algorithm used by arraylist `int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;` in 1.6 and `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);` in 1.7, while adding new element if `oldcapacity` is large then it will create a new backing array with above algorithm and may allocate much unneeded space, if only one element is added after dynamic expansion.

Is my reasoning behind the method correct or there are some other applications to it?

Comment: The resize algorithm (at least in Java 7) is `int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes the backing array is increased by ~50% when it's full. For example, the program below adds 1 million entries, calls `trimToSize` then adds one entry. The backing array's length is 1.2m after adding the entries, 1m after trimming and 1.5m after adding one item.

So unless you know that you won't be adding to the list any longer, calling `trimToSize` could be counter-productive.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Field e = list.getClass().getDeclaredField("elementData");
e.setAccessible(true);
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
System.out.println(((Object[]) e.get(list)).length); //1215487
list.trimToSize();
System.out.println(((Object[]) e.get(list)).length); //1000000
list.add(0);
System.out.println(((Object[]) e.get(list)).length); //1500000
```

Comment: Guess who else is writing an answer right now, and with what point :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Are you going to argue that the method is useless? ;-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you guys are amazing ;) assylias just write him a check and he won't feel bad :D

Comment: You could sum it up like that :) BTW +1 for the caveat about adding after trimming...

Comment: Can i have a question ? what exactly woud be a value of oldcapacity if its value is 100 after   oldcapacity=oldcapacity >>1    ?.... 50? i never seen *>>* used before.

Comment: Yes, `x >> 1` is equivalent to a division by 2 for positive numbers. See [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another situation is when we add elements and then remove many of them. When we remove elements internal aray stays unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula results in worst-case overhead of just 50% of empty slots. Note that the *minimum size* of an `Object` is 24 bytes, compared to just 4 bytes for a compressed OOP in the array. The overhead amounts to just

```
(0.5*4) / (24+4) == 1/14 == 7%
```

which can hardly ever be worth considering—and that's the *worst it can get*. On average it's half the overhead in the array entries, and often the objects are much larger.

So the only time it would make sense to call `trimToSize` is after a massive removal from a previously huge arraylist. In other words, almost never.

Comment: +1 for the last point which is interesting (and the rest of the analysis of course!). However I think the size of an `Object` is 12 bytes (maybe padded to 16), not 24.

Comment: Also the point to consider over here is that if I am making so many removals I might not be using ArrayList at all. I would use Linkedlist. Makes sense?

Comment: @NarendraPathai Probably not... `LinkedList` is quite bad regarding per-element overhead, so whenever `trimToSize` is worth considering, `LinkedList` is out of the question. What I would actually do in such a case is the analogue of a *copying garbage collector*: make a new `ArrayList` and copy the survivors there.

Comment: Hmm. A lot is yet to be learnt. I have not faced such a situation till now. Thanks a lot.